# MySQL　APIの実行時のエラーに関して

Tags: mysql, c, api

Dev C++で下記のソースコードを実行すると下記のエラーが出ます。
このエラーメッセージを解決する方法を教えてください。

```
27  11  C:\Users\patch\Documents\main.cpp   [Error] cannot convert 'char**(MYSQL_RES*) {aka char**(st_mysql_res*)}' to 'MYSQL_ROW {aka char**}' in assignment
28      C:\Users\patch\Documents\Makefile.win   recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

`コードをここに入力`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include/mysql.h>

int main()
//int res(const char *s)
{
  MYSQL *m;
  MYSQL_RES *r;
  MYSQL_ROW w;
  MYSQL_STMT *s;
  MYSQL_BIND par[2];
  MYSQL_BIND res[2];
  char sd[4][60];
  unsigned long sdl[4];
  my_bool nl[4];
  char sql1[]= "SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE host LIKE '%localhost%'";
  char sql2[]= "SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE host LIKE ?";

  mysql_real_connect(m,"localhost","root","","test",0,NULL,0);

  puts("Regular Execution");
  mysql_real_query(m, sql1, strlen(sql1));

  r= mysql_store_result(m);
  while (w= mysql_fetch_row)
  {
    printf("%s@%s\n", w[0], w[1]);
  }

  puts("Prepared Statement");
  mysql_stmt_prepare(s, sql2, strlen(sql2));
  // parameter
  par[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
  par[0].buffer= sd[0];
  par[0].is_null= 0;
  par[0].length= &sdl[0];
  mysql_stmt_bind_param(s,par);

  strncpy(sd[0],"%localhost%",60);
  sdl[0]= strlen(sd[0]);
  mysql_stmt_execute(s);
  res[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
  res[0].buffer= sd[1];
  res[0].buffer_length= 60;
  res[0].is_null= &nl[1];
  res[0].length= &sdl[1];
  res[1].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
  res[1].buffer= sd[2];
  res[1].buffer_length= 60;
  res[1].is_null= &nl[2];
  res[1].length= &sdl[2];
  mysql_stmt_bind_result(s,res);

  while(w= mysql_fetch_row(r))
  {
    printf("%s@%s\n", sd[1], sd[2]);
  }

  mysql_stmt_free_result(s);
  mysql_stmt_close(s);
  mysql_close(m);
}
```

Comment: 最初の `while (w= mysql_fetch_row)` の箇所。しかし次では `while(w= mysql_fetch_row(r))` としている…不思議ですね。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/72670

Answer (score 0):

プログラム中の

```
  while (w= mysql_fetch_row)
```

の部分は

```
  while (w= mysql_fetch_row(r))
```

ではないかと思います。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます。
while(w= mysql_fetch_row(r))を追加してCompileしたら次のエラーメッセージが出てきます。
8 1 C:\Users\patch\Documents\main.cpp [Error] expected initializer before 'int'
28  C:\Users\patch\Documents\Makefile.win recipe for target 'main.o' failed